# Why Does Viewport move on CTRL+ALT+Numpad0 press?

Tags: 3d-view, camera

I can't figure out why my viewport moves around and captures a shifted view when i press `CTRL`+`ALT`+`Numpad0`. I checked and verified that the active camera is correct. Even tried deleting and adding a new camera, the file is at
https://pasteall.org/blend/7a1087aaa8f24fd485d24545b5434bf0

When i create a new file, it works perfectly fine. But when i open the file it does weird shifting movements on the viewport when `CTRL`+`ALT`+`Numpad0` is pressed.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your *View* is locked to the *3D Cursor*, so it's trying to do both things at the same time. Disabling the lock will get rid of that offset, but your camera frame is still panned to the right of the viewport so that will mean some jerkiness when going in and out of the camera view. You can simply pan it towards the center, or use the <kbd>Home</kbd> key to center and fill the view automatically:

[image]

Comment: still same issue for me even after unlocking this option

Comment: but it doesn't happen as violently anymore but still the viewport should not move right?

Comment: Your frame is panned to the right in your camera view because of the previous 3D Cursor lock, simply pressing the Home key to center the frame should get rid of that pan. Try that?

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Edited the answer with a video demonstrating the solution.

Comment: thank you. oh so this is normal that the viewport still moves slightly. thought it will be like when you start a new file where the viewport doesn't move at all when i do CTRL+ALT+0. cool thanks

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie I only now see what you mean by that. It does seem like that if you move the frame while in camera view even just a little bit, from then on it jerks slightly when going in and out. If you somehow can get back to that exact zoom and pan, you can stop it but it's obviously very hard to be that precise. Interesting, I had never paid that much attention to it, I just assumed it was natural.

Answer (score 4):

Disabling "Lock To 3D Cursor" in the View menu seems to fix the problem.

[image]

Comment: still same issue for me even after unlocking this option

Comment: but it doesn't happen as violently anymore but still the viewport should not move right?